# MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata возвращает нечитаему строку для не английских слов/букв

Tags: android

Пытаюсь получить метаданные (название, исполнитель, альбом) из аудиофайлов (.mp3):

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mMetaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mMetaRetriever.setDataSource(path);
String pathMeta =  mMetaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

Но если метаданные не английском языке, а на каком нибудь другом (русский, японский и т.д.), то метод возвращает нечитаему строку (например: Ð³Ð»Ð°Ð²Ð½ÑÐ¹ Ð¸ÑÑÐ¾ÑÐ½Ð¸Ðº ÑÐ»ÐµÐºÑÑÐ¾Ð½Ð½Ð¾Ð¹ Ð¼ÑÐ·ÑÐºÐ¸ Ð²ÐºÐ¾Ð½ÑÐ°ÐºÑÐµ)

Такая проблема только с API 21-25
а вот с KitKat 4.4.4 (API 19) всё нормально (и для версий ниже думаю тоже самое)

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой при чтении метаданных не английском языке используя `MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata` или `MediaStore` (в нем такая же проблема для API 21-25)?

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно проблемы с кодировкой, попробуйте так

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)
```

Comment: кодировками уже наигрался, оказывается проблема что строка вовсе не одна строка, а две, то есть такие метаданные Android (по крайней мере в последних версиях) не умеет обрабатывать, понятно, что символов новой строки не должно быть хранится в таких метаданных, но все же кто-то умудряется впихивать по несколько строк в метаданные